# Create a matrix of subfigures

Tags: subfloats

I am trying to create a figure made of 7 subfigures, whose layout is:

3 subfigures on the first and second row (left aligned, centered and right aligned)

and one subfigure on the third row (left aligned).

The code I wrote is:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{subfigure}[t!]{0.4 \textwidth}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{./capitoli/4/immagini/a_1.png}



    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t!]{0.4 \textwidth}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.23]{./capitoli/4/immagini/a_2.png}
        \end{subfigure}

            \begin{subfigure}[t!]{0.2 \textwidth}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.24]{./capitoli/4/immagini/a_3.png}

    \end{subfigure}

        \begin{subfigure}[c!]{0.25 \textwidth}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{./capitoli/4/immagini/a_4.png}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[c!]{0.2 \textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{./capitoli/4/immagini/a_5.png}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[c!]{0.2 \textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{./capitoli/4/immagini/a_6.png}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b!]{0.2 \textwidth}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{./capitoli/4/immagini/a_7.png}
\end{subfigure}


\end{figure}
```

But it prints two subfigures on the first row and then one left-aligned subfigure for five rows.

Any tips to solve this issue?

[image]

[image]

[image][image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try with `subfloatrow`s environments, from package `floatrow`.

Comment: Just eliminate the blank lines and throw in some `\hfill`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have different sized figures in addition to `\subfigures` of different `width`s, is difficult IMO to achieve your desired layout just adding for example `\hfill` and `\\` (this works well for figures with the same size):

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-a}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.23]{example-image-a}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.2\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.24]{example-image-a}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \\
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{example-image-b}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{example-image-b}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{example-image-b}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \\
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{example-image-c}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \hfill
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Therefore, a simple approach according to the output of your code is using the  `tabular` environment. With `l`, `c` and `r` you can align the figures on the left, center or right; respectively.

Output:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{lcr}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-a} &
    \includegraphics[scale=0.23]{example-image-a} &
    \includegraphics[scale=0.24]{example-image-a} \\
    \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{example-image-b} &
    \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{example-image-b} &
    \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{example-image-b} \\
    \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{example-image-c} & & \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

From presented images in your question I assume that:

- they have equal size,
- they haven't sub captions

so it can be simply arranged in figure as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.3\linewidth}
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
\hfill
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
\hfill
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}

\smallskip
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
\hfill
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
\hfill
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}

\smallskip
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}

\caption{My beautiful images. Quack!}
\label{tab:traintestsplit}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note, empty line between images or text start new text line.